# Don't know how to install app from github

Tags: app, github, install

I'm trying to install Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries from GitHub. Can someone please tell me how to do that?

https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries

When it's properly installed it will be visible in App Menu and in the dropdown under "Getting Started".

Thank you

Comment: There's instructions in the link you provided.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Read the manual in the link provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Where I found the URL]
OK, I finally found the right link to click on, in github, to install this.

From this page:
https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries#packaged-release-history

I went to the latest version, and where it said 
"Package Production URL, Sandbox URL"
I clicked "Production URL", which was the magic link I was looking for all along.

Answer (score 1):

Scroll to the very bottom and click on [image]

Comment: I've tried this. It looks very promising at first - it prints status updates to the screen, the last one saying that the deployment is complete. But then the app doesn't show up under my "Getting Started" dropdown in the upper right corner. Perhaps I have installed it and I just don't know how to launch it - I see that it is in Setup under Manage Apps, App Menu!

Comment: Thank you, I am getting much closer! I have managed to get the app to appear as an option under the Quick Access Menu. Unfortunately, when I choose that option, it doesn't appear to actually launch the app. I'm taken somewhere there is only a Home tab, though it ought to have 4 tabs: "Home"
"Welcome"
"Manage Lookup Rollup Summaries"
"Lookup Rollup Summary Logs"

Comment: Did you set up permissions for the tabs?

Comment: OK, I figured this out. This thing I deployed to Salesforce was the source code and not what I wanted. So when I go into Create, Apps, it's there but there's nothing in the "Installed Package" column. Whereas when someone finally pointed out where the right link was (I answered my own question, details there), it added another row in the Create, Apps page, but this one has something in the "Installed Package" column. And when I get into it, the tabs are there - yay! Thank you all so much for your help. I just could not see that link...